# How would I check if a named program is running in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, tasklist

For some reason it says awesome even when the program is not open, and even if I put in a window name like "asdfsd" or something random. Can anyone help?

```
@echo off
:start
tasklist | find /I "WINDOWNAME"
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo awesome
)
goto :start
```

Comment: Fix your code `%ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1`. You need to try more before posting on stack overflow. You obviously have not tried to resolve this yourself or try to gain the slightest bit of batch knowledge. Fix your syntax and try again.

Comment: See `if /?` and https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html

Comment: What you need to do is to begin by finding out how to use `tasklist.exe`. To begin with, what is your output when you open a command prompt and enter `tasklist | find /I "WINDOWNAME"` _where `WINDOWNAME` is a marker for your actual string_. Now In the same window enter `help tasklist` and read it's usage information. Where did you see mention of the word `WINDOW`? It is used in the filter `WINDOWTITLE`, so you may want to look at using a filter in your command. Additionally try the `/V` option, e.g. `tasklist /V | find /I "WINDOWNAME"`? _where `WINDOWNAME` is a marker for your actual string_.

Comment: @NekoMusume I tried this `if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (` but it still didnt work, the same thing is happening. I tried a bunch of previous answers already, but I couldn't get it to work thats why I made a post.

Comment: `%ERRORLEVEL%` is 1 when there is an error! that means when find cannot find `"WINDOWNAME"` the command will print awesome. Check the links I gave you!

Comment: @NekoMusume - `if errorlevel 1` is perfectly valid and means "if %errorlevel% is 1 or higher"

Comment: @NekoMusume hm I tried with both the window open and the window closed and it was sending the message either way so I don't think thats the problem, though now that I know that it probably just can't find the window somehow. I'll try with a different window to see if it works for that.

Comment: Try `if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (echo awesome)` this will print when the window exists, not when it doesn't exist

Comment: @NekoMusume ok I've been trying it for a while now, I finally figured out that the problem was I was specifying the title but it should be the file. (ie rather than `Untitled - Paint` it should be `paint.exe`). I tried using `WINDOWTITLE eq *the title*` but thats not working, is there something else I need to do for that to work? Its not really necessary though I would prefer it to be that way.

Also I want to thank you for being so patient with me and helping me! :D

Comment: You can use tasklist's filters. Check `tasklist /?` and see the filters. You can do `tasklist /fi "imagename eq paint.exe"`

Comment: **[Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62006534/edit)**, to include all of the up to date information, the exact program name or window title you're looking for in the output from `TaskList`, and the actual output from `TaskList /V` too. Then update your code so that it matches that program name or window title, and preferably doesn't just keep running indefinitly.

Comment: @NekoMusume ok so I tried a few things to check the window title.
`tasklist | find /I "WINDOWTITLE eq Untitled - Paint"`
`tasklist /Fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Untitled - Paint"`
However none of them work, the first one is always error code of 1 and the second is error code of 2. (no matter if its opened or close). The second one does give an output which shows whether its found it or not.

It says `INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.` when it hasnt found anything and it gives a table with one entry (the window I have open) when it is open.

Comment: That may be since there are spaces, try `tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq untitled*`

Comment: @NekoMusume i tried that but its not working, I think the filter part is correct since it gave an output (atleast on one of my attempts), it just gives an error code of 0 no matter what. I'll keep looking for something.

Comment: @aschipfl thanks a lot! It works. Is the /V necessary? When I have it in it takes a while to do, when I remove it it goes nearly instantly (and it still works). Is there some other reason why you would have it?

I think your comment is removed somehow aswell because I can't see it anymore.

Comment: You're welcome! I converted my comment to an answer now. Furthermore, I reverted your edit, because you should not implement solutions in a question, because then any answers do not make much sense anymore. Please check out this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)...

Comment: The `/V` option was just a left-over from checking the code, but it is not necessary, the filter `/FI` does not at all depend on it...

Comment: @aschipfl Ah ok sorry didn't know that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, let me recommend not to use `find` just to find a certain window title in the whole output of `tasklist`, because the search string might occur somewhere else, like the image name, for example, which could lead to false matches.

Anyway, the [`tasklist` command](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) does not set the [exit code (`ErrorLevel`)](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) when the filter `/FI` does not find a match, but you could check whether the output begins with `INFO:`, which is the case when no match was encountered:

```cmd
:start
timeout /T 1
tasklist /FI "WindowTitle eq WindowName" | findstr /B "INFO:" > nul && (echo goto :start) || (echo awesome)`.
```

This depends on the returned single line in case of no matches:

> ```cmd
> INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.
> ```

This text depends on the locale/region/language settings of the system. To make this even locale-independent, you could use the a trick: `tasklist`, with default output format (`/FO TABLE`), returns more than a single line when at least a match is encountered, because there is a two-line header followed by the actual matching items; if there is no match, the aforementioned line is the only one returned. So capture the output of `tasklist` by a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), using the option `skip=1`. The `for /F` loop will then set the exit code to `1` (not the `ErrorLevel` though) when it does not iterate, and to `0` when it iterates at least once. This exit code can be checked using the [conditional execution operators `&&` and `||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
:start
timeout /T 1
(for /F "skip=1" %%I in ('tasklist /FI "WindowTitle eq WindowName"') do rem/) && (echo awesome) || (goto :start)
```

I inserted the [`timeout` command](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) in order to avoid heavy CPU loads by the `goto :start` loop.